# Mysqli prepared insert with nested selects fails in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I'm trying to insert some date to MySQL table with prepared insert with nested 3 nested selects in it. The thing is that for all nested selects a single variable is used. Actual SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO db_test.offers
  (`id`,`catalog_service_id`,`offer_name`,
  `offer_description`,`offer_url`,
  `offer_interaction_format`,`offer_methods`)
VALUES(1,
(SELECT `catalog_service_id` FROM db_test.catalog_services
   WHERE `catalog_service_code` = ?),
(SELECT `catalog_service_name` FROM db_test.catalog_services
   WHERE `catalog_service_code` = ?),
(SELECT `catalog_service_name` FROM db_test.catalog_services
   WHERE `catalog_service_code` = ?),
'https://url.com', 'json', 'CC');
```

PHP code:

```
class test extends mysqli{
function db_action($host = null){
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, "db_test");
    if(!$mysqli){
        die ("couldn't connect to mysql host" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
$codes= ["AAAAA005760000000001","ААААА032680000000001","ААААА032680000000002"];
$query="SQL code from above";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt ->bind_param("sss", $offer, $offer, $offer);
    foreach ($codes as $k => $offer) {
        if($stmt->execute() === false){
            print 'Wrong SQL. Error: ' . $stmt->error . "\r\n";
        }else{
            $last_inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
            print "Insert row with id: " . $last_inserted_id . " for service_code: ". $offer . "\r\n";
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

First iteration of foreach works fine (1 row is inserted with correct data), but on 2nd and 3rd (just for an example, real number of elements in $codes array is unknown). The The executed statement on the sql-server is executed with question marks instead of actual value. When I go through the function in debugger - the value of $offer var changes on each iteration of for each.

SQL error that comes from the server is obvious: catalog_service_id cannot be null.

table info:

```
CREATE TABLE `offers` (
      `offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `catalog_service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `offer_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `offer_start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `offer_stop_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `offer_url` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
      `offer_auth` enum('Basic','Digest') DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_auth_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_auth_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_auth_secret` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_operator_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `public_offer_url` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
      `offer_interaction_format` enum('urlencoded','json') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'urlencoded',
      `offer_methods` enum('CC','MC') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MC',
      `offer_inn` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_kpp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_min` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `offer_max` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`offer_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm really stuck...

Comment: Shouldn't the `bind_param()` statement be inside the foreach, not before it?

Comment: thanks for a reply. I've tried that before and checked it right now. Nothing change...

Comment: I have run the code and there is nothing obviously incorrect. However, your test data `ААААА03268`, the 'AAAAA' is not the ASCII 'A'. This will cause errors if your `category_services` table does not contain the exact same key. As already mentioned you do need the `bind_param` inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: [working code at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/i5qNnYSv)

Comment: Well, heh :) Thanks a lot, Ryan. That's really was because of not an ASCII 'A' letters. That's realy odd, because I've just tried to query `catalog_services` with 'broken' strings and it works fine (but returns different `id`, `offer_name` and `offer_description`).